# How is someone's "power level" determined in Dragonball Z?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

How is a Dragonball character's power level determined numerically? What exactly is measured?

[image: It is over nine thousands?]

**This particular image depicts a moment where Vegeta vociferously reacts to the scanner's readout of Goku's power level being above the 9000 measurement.*

Comment: power level = ki level usually.

Comment: Multiply episode number by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Power Level](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Power_level) is a reading of a persons current Ki.

> The actual term "Power Level" usually refers to readings produced by scouters, which are sensory devices used by Frieza's crew that detect a person's ki. The reading is converted into numbers of an unspecified unit, and the resulting number is the "Power Level", or an estimation of that person's physical capability.
>
> It is first introduced in Dragon Ball, where a young Goku learns to
>   sense ki after drinking the Ultra Divine Water, although the Z
>   Fighters are able to detect power levels via the ki sensing ability
>   eventually.